# res.forbidden error on file upload into sails

Tags: node.js, upload, sails.js

I'm having an odd issue in node/sails and difficultly troubleshooting. I can upload small xls files via a upload form but larger ones do not process/upload, here is a simple test, when passed a small file (500-1000 rows) it processes fine and I get console logs. A large (20,000 row) file just spins on uploading.

My form looks like this:

```
        <div class="row col-xs-12">
        <form id="uploadForm"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              action="/utility/test_req"
              method="post">
            <label for="Parse Through Row" class="control-label">Parse</label>
            <input type="text" name="num_rows" />
            <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload CSV"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
test_req: function (req, res, next){
    console.log("here");
    console.log(req.params.all());
    res.redirect('/utility/migration')
},
```

Comment: Zagen: just updated with code, any ideas?

Comment: @endencorbin did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes tried it and it worked.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `_crsf` token to the top of the form, i believe input fields are sent in order by the browser, and hence, parsed in the same order by sails. csrf tokens are time constrained so you get a short window of usage before they get invalidated, then if you have a big file, first your file gets processed(or files) and when sails is done with that it will parse your token, but then is too late.

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
    // The rest of the inputs here, including the file input.
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload CSV"/>
</form>
```

It should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a csrf issue. Disabling csrf globally allows the controller action to be reached with larger files. I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue (likely) or a bug with csrf or sails (unlikely).